# Trace.WriteLine(message, category) without leading Category in output

Tags: c#, visual-studio, trace

The `Trace.WriteLine(message, category)` traces for a certain category, e.g. "Information"
and it prints `Information: message`.

Just out of curiosity: is it possible to tell `Trace` to not output the leading "Information: " prefix while still using the category?

I need `Trace` and category for other reasons, so just out of curiosity: in this scenario is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

`Trace` class doesn't support this by default.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Though you may provide custom implementation of `CustomTraceListener` object
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650498.aspx
to write in desirable way to console or anywhere you need and add it to the list of Trace listeners

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.Listeners.Clear();
System.Diagnostics.Trace.Listeners.Add(...);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y5y10s7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I hoped esp. for existing trace listeners to optionally not do that.